# Python regex to extract html paragraph

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract parapgraphs from HTML by using the following line of code:

```
paragraphs = re.match(r'<p>.{1,}</p>', html)
```

but it returns none even though I know there is. Why?

Comment: Argh!!! [Stop using regular expressions to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/364696). We have proper HTML and XML parsers for this. For HTML, use [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) (Py2) or [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) (Py3) or a third party package like BeautifulSoup. If it's true XHTML, you can use a more strict parser that can parse iteratively, e.g. [`xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse). DON'T USE REGEXES!

Comment: ...Horrible use of regex aside, isn't `.{1,}` just "any character one or more times"? Why on Earth wouldn't you use `.+` for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't use an *HTML parser* to, well, [parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
...     <div>
...         <p>text1</p>
...         <p></p>
...         <p>text2</p>
...     </div>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> [p.get_text() for p in soup.find_all("p", text=True)]
[u'text1', u'text2']
```

Note that `text=True` helps to filter out empty paragraphs.

Comment: Note that extracting paragraphs with BeautifulSoup can be about two orders of magnitude slower than a regexp-based solution. This is something to keep in mind if performance is important for your application.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you use `re.search` (or `re.findall`) instead of `re.match`, which attempts to match the entire html string (your html is definitely not beginning and ending with `<p>` tags).

Should also note that currently your search is greedy meaning it will return everything between the *first* `<p>` tag and the last `</p>` which is something you definitely do not want. Try

```
re.findall(r'<p(\s.*?)?>(.*?)</p>', response.text, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

instead. The question mark will make your regex stop matching at the first closing `</p>` tag, and `findall` will return multiple matches compared to `search`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `re.search` instead of `re.match`. The former will search the entire string whereas the latter will only match if the pattern is at the beginning of the string.

That said, regular expressions are a horrible tool for parsing HTML. You will hit a wall with them very shortly. I strongly recommend you look at HTMLParser or BeautifulSoup for your task.

Comment: This for recommending a real DOM parser.